# SQL for Game Scores & Prediction System

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building a Hockey Sports score and prediction system using PHP/MySQL. Below are the system design.

I have a GAMES table where two team numbers and their score in the game is present.The columns from this table are as below.

```
ID ---- TEAM1 ---- SCORE1 ---- TEAM2 ---- SCORE2
1       70         1           73         2
2       74         0           70         1
3       74         0           73         0
```

I also have a PICKS table where the details related to user's game predictions are present. Users can guess which team will win in a game and that data is stored in this table. The columns from this table are as below. Each user can guess only once for each game.

```
ID ---- GAME ---- USER ---- TEAM ---- POINT
1       1         1         70        1
2       2         1         70        1
3       3         1         73        1
3       1         2         70        1
```

Based on the above available data, I am trying to build up the result where each user (column USER) should be awarded the points(column POINT) for each correct guess. The guess can be validated based on the scores from GAMES table. The final output should be like as below.

```
USER ---- POINTS ---- CORRECT GUESS COUNT ---- WRONG GUESS COUNT
1         1           1                        2
2         0           0                        1
```

The columns "CORRECT GUESS COUNT" and "WRONG GUESS COUNT" represent the total number of correct guess and wrong guess done by the user.

I have created a SQL Fiddle for the above tables with some sample data.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d469/4/0

**EDIT:**

- Some more inforamtion are below. It's possible that a game can be a
  draw.
- In that case the score will be 0 for each team. When a game is
  draw, users get no points.

Comment: Is `game` in `PICKS` a Foreign Key for `id` in `GAMES`?

Comment: Yes @PM77-1. We will not have any other Game other than present in the GAMES table.

Comment: Yes Sir. Draws are possible. In that case the scores will be 0 for each team in GAMES table.

Comment: Which team wins in "0:0" game? Both or none?

Comment: None of the team wins in a draw. So users will not get any points. Sorry for not providing those details. I will edit the question now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38812/discussion-between-purus-and-pm-77-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.user, 
       SUM(IF(g.id IS NOT NULL, p.point, 0)) As points, 
       SUM(IF(g.id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) Correct,
       SUM(IF(g.id IS NULL, 1, 0)) Wrong

FROM Games g 
RIGHT JOIN Picks p ON g.id = p.game AND 
          p.team = IF(g.score1 > g.score2 , g.team1, IF(g.score1 < g.score2, g.team2, NULL))
GROUP BY p.user;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d469/53) (with your data)

Comment: Works perfectly. Accepted the answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to forgive me, if there is a more MySQL way to do it than this (background is Oracle/SQL Server):

```
SELECT
  p.user
  ,sum(CASE
     WHEN p.team = g.winner THEN point ELSE 0 END) points
,sum(CASE
     WHEN p.team = g.winner THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) good_guess
,sum(CASE
     WHEN p.team <> g.winner THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) bad_guess
FROM
  picks p
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    id game_id
    ,CASE
       WHEN score1 > score2 THEN team1
       WHEN score2 > score1 THEN team2
       ELSE -1 --no team_id as negative
    END winner
    FROM
      games
) g
ON
  g.game_id = p.game
GROUP BY
  p.user
```

Comment: Thanks. The previous answer looks simple. Thanks again for your time on this.